# How to check lang attribute support in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

How to check in javascript, if the elements support the HTML5 lang attribute?

Comment: use this framworks that check html5 : http://www.modernizr.com/

Comment: lang attribute is part of generic attributes even on html4: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#coreattrs - why do you need to check its support via js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.  HTML(5) does not have any built-in validation capabilities.  If HTML were an instance of a schema language then you could easily validate against the schema.

Comment: then I make it with try catch